# Comentários com Facebook para notícias diferentes em site

Tags: php, facebook, plugin

Estou desenvolvendo um site que terá várias postagens diferentes (como um blog, por exemplo). Adicionei o plugin de comentar com Facebook, para que os usuários que acessam poderem comentar. Porém, estou na seguinte situação:

O usuário acessa uma notícia: nomedosite.com/noticias?id=1

A noticia é exibida e ao final o sistema de comentários é exibido. Quando o usuário comenta, o comentário fica salvo. Mas ao abrir outra notícia:

nomedosite.com/noticias?id=2

, os comentários da notícia anterior aparecem junto. Preciso que cada notícia tenha sua 'linha' de comentários. Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom dia..
É muito fácil resolver o problema que você está tendo. Na [API do Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments) existe um parâmetro a ser passado no código que você trava aquele objeto dos comentários com a URL que você decidir.

Se no seu site tem uma notícia que está na URL http://meusitebacana.com/noticia-2, no código você irá implementar assim:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://meusitebacana.com/noticia-2" data-numposts="5">
</div>
```

Onde o **data-href** irá definir ao facebook qual a url da notícia que você quer os comentários.

No PHP, no desenrolar da programação, você escreve essa url aí.

**É importante frisar que:** Esta URL não pode ser dinâmica, sendo que se você montar ela assim: `$url = "http://".$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]."/".$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];` e a pessoa acessar `http://meusitebacana.com/noticia-2?utm_source=google`, a URL vai ficar diferente e o objeto dos comentários também vai ser outro. Então vai haver duplicidade de comentários à uma única URL (Que não é o que você espera).

A [API do Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments) monta o código pra você, é só acessar.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Nada a ver! No API não tem nada disso aí. Tudo errado. Duplicidade dos comentários é impossível a não ser que o usuário comentasse duas vezes. O API não monta nada, ele tem é uma documentação com código para implementação de plugins .

Comment: Com o URL canonico definido na implementação, ele vai comentar o url definido, independente do que tiver de variável dependurada no final do url. Da mesma forma que se ele estiver definido só vai comentar e exibir comentarios do URL definido. Mas sem a implementação completa não vai comentar é nada. Quem é o moderador dos comentários... ehn

Comment: @DavidAugustus , Olha o site da Documentação do Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments ... O primeiro passo é 'Escolha a URL ou a Página' !! Eu posso ter errado em não dizer que devia ser uma URL cannonical , até porque na época eu não conhecia o termo. Mas não errei em como funciona a API.

Comment: whatyson o api é outra coisa. vc se refere ao gerador de codigo .. nesse caso ai o canonical é coisa do seu codigo... me chama no fb.me/davidaugustus42 pq ess3s bosta desses admin n deixam eu ajudar ..

Comment: eai conseguiu ou ainda não

Answer (score -2):

Para implementar o Comentários, você precisa de 3 coisas, primeiro é o Open Graph, pra definir as propriedades da página que será comentada, incluindo, eventualmente, URL canonico. Segundo, é o SDK do Facebook. Terceiro, o elemento de marcação do Plugin. Neste elemento, você deverá especificar o objeto ou seja o URL que será comentado por este plugin. Se este elemento estiver fora de uma estrutura por exemplo:
Tem um produto dentro da página, que tem cabeça~lho e rodapé .
Se você colocar ele dentro do conteúdo dinamico do produto, com a URL especifica, vai funcionar cada vez um. Mas voce pode tambem ter um no rodapé, especificando qualquer um dos  URLS que preferir. Lembrando que PARA COMENTAR ALGO, deVe se saber O QUE SERÁ COMENTADO, pois o plugin não é simplesmente uma ferramenta para coletar comentários e exibi-los. Ele gera atividades dentro do Facebook, muito significantes para o desempenho da distribuição do conteúdo. No caso notícias deve ser categorizado como tipo noticias. E deve conter informações sobre data da publicação, assim como do autor. Tem vários outros detalhes, para implementar o comentários, você deve procurar Open Graph antes e depois o botão Curtir e Compartilhar para sites .

Comment: Olá @David. A sua resposta está muito confusa. Procure ser mais claro, coloque inclusive código se for necessário. Mas mais importante estruture o texto.

Comment: Verdade @JoãoMartins. Recomendamos que você acesse o guia de como formatar perguntas e respostas, disponível nesse [link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas?cb=1). Pode te ajudar a melhorar as suas respostas/perguntas e também a esclarecer algumas dúvidas.